# Angular AOT-compiler inconsistent complaints

Tags: angular

So I keep getting the error that looks like this `"Property 'xxxx' is private and only accessible within class 'yyyy'."`
And from what I have read this is because of the AOT-compilation requires that all variables accessed by the template needs to be public.

But the strange thing is it's extremely inconsistent. Some variables seams to be fine being private even tough I'm using them in the template. Why is this?

Here's an example of a variable that the AOT-compiler complains about: https://github.com/UnionVMS/VMS-Frontend/blob/731b87d139c733db65f16923cadad86943346adb/app/src/app/modules/map/pages/realtime/realtime.component.ts#L71

Here's an example where it dosn't complain: https://github.com/UnionVMS/VMS-Frontend/blob/731b87d139c733db65f16923cadad86943346adb/app/src/app/modules/map/pages/realtime/realtime.component.ts#L61

Can anyone shed any light on why it's like this?
Why are some variables okay and others not? I can't find the reason for this.

Comment: If you change `centerMapOnPosition` to public - does it complain about the other method?

Comment: @yccteam: No, it works just fine. The other variable has been there and been working for many weeks.